# Aggregate objects in ElasticSearch by IP Prefix

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, ip-address, elasticsearch-aggregation

I have an ElasticSearch index where I store internet traffic flow objects, which each object containing an IP address. I want to aggregate the data in a way that all objects with the same IP Prefix are collected in the same bucket (but without specifying a specific Prefix). Something like a histogram aggregation. Is this possible?

I have tried this:

```
GET flows/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "ip_ranges": {
      "histogram": {
        "field": "ipAddress",
        "interval": 256
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But this doesn't work, probably because histogram aggregations aren't supported for ip type fields. How would you go about doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, As suggested [here](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/histogram-aggregation-on-ip-addresses/79175/2), the best approach would be to:

> categorize the IP address at index time and then use a simple keyword field to store the class c information, and then use a term aggregation on that field to do the count.

Alternatively, you could simply add a [multi-field](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/multi-fields.html) [keyword mapping](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/keyword.html):

```json
PUT myindex
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "ipAddress": {
        "type": "ip",
        "fields": {
          "keyword": {         <---
            "type": "keyword"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

and then extract the prefix at query time (⚠️ highly inefficient!):

```json
GET myindex/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "my_prefixes": {
      "terms": {
        "script": "/\\./.split(doc['ipAddress.keyword'].value)[0]",
        "size": 10
      }
    }
  }
}
```

As a final option, you could define the intervals of interest in advance and use an [`ip_range` aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-iprange-aggregation.html):

```json
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "my_ip_ranges": {
      "ip_range": {
        "field": "ipAddress",
        "ranges": [
          { "to": "192.168.1.1" },
          { "from": "192.168.1.1" }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for answering the question! This helps a lot :)

Comment: You're welcome! Hey my Elasticsearch Handbook is coming out very soon -- you can [sign up here](https://jozefsorocin.typeform.com/to/XeQRxdwV) and let me know what else besides regexes in ES you'd like to learn about. I'll then let you know when the handbook is out!